# I want virtocommerce in my own local repository.(include storefront, platform and modules). How to setup all of these in my solutions?

Tags: virtocommerce

I want virtocommerce in my own local repository.
storefront is a solution that will configure it according to the following link:
[Storefront Source Code Getting Started](https://virtocommerce.com/docs/vc2devguide/deployment/storefront-deployment/storefront-source-code-getting-started)
And it works.

But I want to have a solution For platforms and modules,
Like the link below:

[vc-integrations](https://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-integrations/tree/master/PLATFORM/Modules)

But I need the platform and modules to be connected to the github for the latest changes.

I've studied the link below:

[Source Code Getting Started](https://virtocommerce.com/docs/vc2devguide/deployment/platform-deployment/source-code-getting-started)

but I do not understand how should I configure for my goals (one solution for platfrom and modules and fork, clone ,upstream  for all for get latest versions of them)

Answer (score 0):

We've used to have a single repository and single solution for Virto Commerce Manager and modules (vc-integrations). It was difficult to maintain and release often. That's why the single repository was split into many "1 module per repository" pieces.

We consider that in most cases having only Virto Commerce Manager configured should be sufficient. **What's your scenario?** Check "Manual module installation from source code" section in [Source Code Getting Started](https://virtocommerce.com/docs/vc2devguide/deployment/platform-deployment/source-code-getting-started) to get started.

Comment: Here is another doc will help to better understanding VC development process https://virtocommerce.com/docs/vc2devguide/development-scenarios/developing-a-custom-solution